# Wordpress: how to grab an array value from a print_r($object)

Tags: php, wordpress, object

In a Wordpress page template, I'm using:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`meta_key`) FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'mepr-address-state' && `meta_value` = 'NSW';";
    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    print_r($myrows[0]);
?>
```

This outputs:

```
stdClass Object ( [COUNT(`meta_key`)] => 764 )
```

How do I output / print only the value `764` using an alternative to `print_r($myrows[0]);` please?

Comment: `echo $myrows[0]->{"COUNT(`meta_key`)"}` ?

Comment: @splash58, I receive `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$COUNT(meta_key)`

Comment: Well,  let's go right way, `$sql = "SELECT COUNT(meta_key) as cnt FROM...` and `echo $myrows[0]->cnt;`

Comment: @splash58 used backticks around `meta_key`. You didn't. Also you could try with `echo current(get_object_vars($myrows[0]))`. Using an alias as suggested is the correct way to go.

Comment: @revo, yes, missed  backticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value you want with

```
echo $myrows[0]->{'COUNT(`meta_key`)'};
```

But I would really recommend just changing your query to something like this, using an alias for the `COUNT(...)`:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(`meta_key`) AS meta_count FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'mepr-address-state' && `meta_value` = 'NSW';";
```

Then you can just use

```
echo $myrows[0]->meta_count;
```